# Run through a for loop once

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am using Python to run a groundwater model
 My problem is as follows:

I have a three groundwater models stored in the list Model_Names [SLOW, MEDIUM, FAST]
 Each model has different properties and a different modelname i.e SLOW

My script generates input files for the models which are specific to each modelname

I am running the three models in series, with each model run 5 times for a total of 15 runs.
 Groundwater levels are generated each time.

With the exception of the first run of each model (where levels are set), the levels simulated in
 the previous simulation are set as starting levels in the next simulation.
 i.e starting level in SLOW(i) = simulated level in SLOW(i-1)

However, I do not want to use simulated levels from different models
 ie. I don't want levels simulated in a SLOW aquifer to inform a MEDIUM aquifer simulation.

So I am trying to write a for loop that will check if the modelname is equal to the previous modelname
 and then determine which input files to use.

But I am having problems working out the code to use that specifies a previous iteration of a loop

I have tried the following code, where I wanted the current modelname printed and compared to

```
for m, modelname in enumerate(Model_Name):
    print('Model Name = ' +modelname)

    if m!=0 and modelname == Model_Name[m-1]: 
    print ('** STARTING HEAD INPUT FILE UPDATED WITH HEADS FROM PREVIOUS SIMULATION') 

else:
    print('** STARTING HEAD INPUT FILE BUILT ')
```

But it compares modelname(i) to modelname (i-1) three times because it loops the entire length of Model_Names.
 I want it to only check if modelnames(i) == modelnames(i-1) once for each model run and not loop the entire length of Model_Names.  Is there a way to check the modelname of each model run without looping through Model_Names?

I also tried using

```
while modelname == modelname[i-1]:
```

I can't find any reference to
 what I would like to do.

Sorry, I should have mentioned that the for loop is nested within another for loop:

```
Lag_times = [0.0000864, 0.000864, 0.00864]
Manage_Freq = [30, 183, 365, 730, 1825, 3650, 18250] 
Model_Name = ['SLOW', 'MEDIUM', 'FAST']       
# Loop through each model variable, build and run model
for i, j in zip (Lag_times, Model_Name):
    hk = i                           # set hydraulic conductivity
    modelname = j                                            
    for k in Manage_Freq:                          
        Freq = k                      
        # The code in here builds and runs model
```

## Then I want to check if the modelname of the model run is equal to the previous #modelname

```
if modelname !=0 and modelname == Model_Name[modelname-1]: 
              print (' STARTING HEAD INPUT FILE UPDATED WITH HEADS FROM PREVIOUS SIMULATION')     
 else:
              print('** STARTING HEAD INPUT FILE BUILT ')
```

I don’t think I need to loop through Model_Names, but I can’t work out what code to input to check if modelname(i) == modelname(i-1) without using Model_Names.

Comment: The for-loop should only cover the length of `Model_Name` once, not three times. Please [edit] your post to fix the indentation of your code

Comment: Yes, it compares modelname(i) to modelname (i-1) three times (actually two times for a list of length 3) because you are trying to compare the current name to the previous one... Still unclear what you want.

Comment: Sorry, will rephrase question

Comment: You have to iterate over the list to compare the `i` element to the `i-1` element. There is no way around that.

Comment: You can use dictionary using model name as the key to store the last simulated level.  Then in each iteration you can use the model name to look up the last simulated level.

Comment: You could add `break` into the body of the if statement to *exit* the loop and stop comparing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused about what `enumerate` does. You loop will run three times.

(assuming `ModelNames==['Slow','Med','Fast']`)

1. 1st iteration. m will be 0 and modelname will be 'Slow'
2. 2nd iteration. m will be 1 and modelname will be 'Med'
3. 3rd iteration. m will be 2 and modelname will be 'Fast'

So `modelname == ModelNames[m-1]` will always be `True`!

Try writing down what you actually want to do and the code will write itself:

For every model, you want to do 5 runs. The first run will have some special initial parameters, but the next run will have the parameters from the previous run.

Your code would look something like this:

```
for model in ModelNames: # do something for each model
    params=None #initialize parameters to none meaning they're not set yet
    for i in range(5): #do 5 iterations
        if params is None: #have we gotten new starting parameters?
            params=get_initial_params(model) #figure out the ones for the first run
        output=run_simulation(model,params) #do your simulation
        params=get_next_params(output) #get the next parameters
```